# Keep receiving error python-opencv 3.4.2 error: (-215:Assertion failed) (size_t)knn <= index_->size() in function 'runKnnSearch_'

Tags: assertion, opencv, python

I am trying to compare two images but I keeping getting errors in python it says:

> ````
> matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)
> cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /home/pi/opencv
> python/opencv/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp:487: error: (-215:Assertion failed)
> (size_t)knn <= index_->size() in function 'runKnnSearch_'```
> ````

here below is code:

```
# Create Sift
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp_1, desc_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(original, None)

index_params = dict(algorithm=0, trees=15)
search_params = dict()
**flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)** >Is this correct

# Load all images into array
all_images_to_compare = []
titles = []
for f in glob.iglob("/home/pi/dataset/*"):
image = cv2.imread(f)
titles.append(f)
all_images_to_compare.append(image)

for image_to_compare, title in zip(all_images_to_compare, titles):
# 1) Check if 2 images are equals
if original.shape == image_to_compare.shape:
    print("The images have same size and channels")
    difference = cv2.subtract(original, image_to_compare)
    b, g, r = cv2.split(difference)

    if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) == 0:
        print ("Similarity: 100% (equal size and channels)")


#2) Check for similarities between the 2 images
kp_2, desc_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(image_to_compare, None)

**matches = flann.knnMatch(desc_1, desc_2, k=2)** > error occurs here
```